# ¿Cómo hago un condicional para ocurra cierta acción cuando no tenga ningún valor en un entry de Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Este es mi código, pero no sé cuál es el valor que debo poner cuando no tenga nada el entry:

```
codigo=self.productoCod.get()
if codigo==0 or codigo=="VALOR CUANDO NO HAYA NADA":
     self.t6.config(text="")
     self.t8.config(text="")
```

Comment: self.productoCod que es? Un stringvar, un entry, un intvar, etc? Por que si es un intvar, codigo te dará un error si el entry está vacío. La respuesta a tu pregunta depende de esta pregunta que te hice.

Comment: self.productoCod  es un intvar

Comment: Te recomiendo usar StringVar cuando se trata de un entry. Pues si el entry está vacío, tratar de obtener el contenido del IntVar te dará error. Te parecería bien usar un stringvar en lugar de un intvar?

Comment: Está bien, puedo hacerlo y restringirlo a que solo valide números y con un int() convertirlo a número

Comment: Si usas stringvar, lo que devuelva el get será una cadena. Si el entry está vacío, el valor será una cadena vacía. Por lo que en conclusión tu condicional debería de quedar así: `if(codigo == "" or int(codigo) == 0)`. En este caso el orden de las condiciones SI importa, pues si evaluamos la segunda condición primero y el entry está vacío, se va a intentar convertir a entero dicha cadena vacía y ocurrirá un error. En cambio si el entry está vacío la primera condición dará true y, por lo tanto, la segunda condición no será evaluada.

Comment: Lo intentare, y te digo jajaja Gracias :)

Comment: Dale, suerte y de nada :D

Comment: funciono, gracias!! :0